# What is the difference between copying whole website to server and MSDeploy kind of tools

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc

Maybe i'm totally outdated but for last four years i've been using simple FTP upload feature while uploading new website even without building it within Visual Studio. Just bunch of ASPX and CS files as in Visual Studio.

I do understand that compiling the project will provide me with some security defence so ones who have access to the server won't be able to read those files in text editors and i will avoid first time compilation but is that so important?

I mean, you can always do a lot of harm if you have access to server that just reading CS files instead of DLL.

First time compilation usually takes no more than 1 minute just searching for compiled version of the site will take as much time.

Now i'm watching video on PluralSight which explains new MSDeploy tool available from ASP.NET and i can't see any good reason to use it.

So what's wrong with the old fashioned way of just sending files via FTP without compiling or using fancy tools?

I did speed test and with MSDeploy i can deploy a website twice faster than old-fashioned FTPing. So instead of 4 minutes it will take 2.

Now from another perspective, when i already have alive project on the web. In which have to change Default.aspx because i have typo in some html tag. Deployment via MSDeploy will take 10 times more than uploading one file

Maybe i miss something?

Comment: DLLs can be trivially decompiled.  Uploading `.cs` files is not more secure than uploading a DLL.

Comment: Yeah, i just never wanted it to look like a rant on MS deployment teachings.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you deploy a project you can do a lot of things with it.

You can set up a job in your deploy that packages all your javascript into one file and all your css into one file.

You can set up a job in your deployment that changes a bunch of config settings to match your production server settings (rather then development settings).

The idea of deployment is that you take your current development website and transform it into a production website without having to do any of that manually.

The most **important** thing is that when you can *only* deploy your website you will never forget to package your js or forget to remove some debugging code because you can't just sneakly update a single file.

Comment: I understand that but the question is do you understand that writing such advanced deploy script will require more or less the same time than configuring those files manually?

Comment: @eugeneK except you write the script once ;) You have to reconfigure the files manually every time you redeploy.

Comment: Point taken, so if my project require constant changes in environment i should use automation tools.

Comment: @eugeneK we redeploy our product every two weeks with a new version, making all the changes by hand every time would get tedious.

Answer (score 3):

MSDeploy does things which FTPing to a site can't do. Need to change a machine.config? You're unlikely to have FTP write access to the folder which contains it. Want to change a server setting in a server-version-independent manner? FTP won't do that. Etc. FTP works fine for copying files to folders in which you have write access, but that's *all* it can do.

Comment: If you don't have a access to machine.config maybe this is how it should be? You can always edit it if you have an access to server. More important how many projects and how much information do you need to change in machine.config compared to "quick" deployment methods like MS Deploy.

Comment: @eugene, there's a difference between having access to machine.config and opening up the system directory to FTP access. Regarding changing machine.config, yes, this is often necessary -- e.g., an AppFabric connect string goes there by default.

Comment: Cool, i gave this answer to Raynos because you said more or less the same thing but he has lower score than you do. Thanks anyway ...